# Video files transferring getting error while Transfer files from one location to another

Tags: java, c#, console-application

While trying the Code for transferring the files from one location to another location in c#, we are getting error on video file(.mp4) is transferring, but rest of the files are transferring on change.
Timer method is used for ,

```
        static void Main()
        {
            double intervalMilliseconds = 30000;
            timer = new Timer(intervalMilliseconds);
            timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
            timer.AutoReset = true;
            timer.Start();
            var fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(sourceFolder);
            fileSystemWatcher.Created += FileSystemWatcherCreated;
            fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            Console.WriteLine("File transfer scheduled. Press Enter to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            TransferFiles();
        }

        private static void FileSystemWatcherCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            TransferFiles();
        }

        private static void TransferFiles()
        {
            try
            {
                var mostRecentFile = GetMostRecentFile();

                if (mostRecentFile != null)
                {
                    string sourceFilePath = Path.Combine(sourceFolder, mostRecentFile);
                    string destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(destinationFolder, mostRecentFile);

                    UploadFile(sourceFilePath, destinationFilePath);
                    Console.WriteLine("File transferred successfully: {mostRecentFile} at {DateTime.Now}");
                    lastTransferTimestamp = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        private static string GetMostRecentFile()
        {
            try
            {
                var supportedExtensions = new[] { ".txt", ".pdf", ".mp4", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif" };
                var files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder)
                    .Select(filePath => new FileInfo(filePath))
                    .Where(fileInfo =>
                        fileInfo.CreationTime > lastTransferTimestamp &&
                        supportedExtensions.Contains(fileInfo.Extension.ToLower()))
                    .OrderByDescending(fileInfo => fileInfo.CreationTime);
                return files.FirstOrDefault().Name;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        private static void UploadFile(string sourceFilePath, string destinationFilePath)
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.UploadFile(destinationFilePath, "POST", sourceFilePath);
            }
        }
```

any one can you share with any alternative Solutions in `C#` or in `JAVA`

Answer (score 0):

To ensure more consistent file transfers, you can modify the code by adjusting a few things:

1. **Add Timer Declaration:**
   Make sure the `timer` declaration is at class level:

   ```cs
   private static Timer timer;
   ```
2. **Set Timer Interval:**
   Adjust the timer interval as needed. Currently set to 30,000 milliseconds (30 seconds).

   ```cs
   double intervalMilliseconds = 30000;
   timer = new Timer(intervalMilliseconds);
   ```
3. **Fix Format String:**
   In this section, make sure to use double curly braces to print the value of the `mostRecentFile` variable.

   ```cs
   Console.WriteLine($"File transferred successfully: {mostRecentFile} at {DateTime.Now}");
   ```

By making these changes, you can ensure that timers are set correctly, intervals are appropriate, and debug information is more accurate when printing messages to the console.

Comment: this is the code message change only, i need to transfer the .mp4 and all other files. files from one server to another server. Already the static files i created. as in the class level. By this change the vedio files will not transfer. {}